# How to reference dynamic last row of an excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, burndowncharts

I have a function here that I'm using for a burndown chart in Excel. This is the initial burndown function below. I would like to replace row H56 with the end of my table (in case the date changes, I don't have to keep updating this value), but I can't figure out how with this complicated formula. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
=$H$2-(($H$2)/ROWS($H$2:$H$56))*(ROWS($H$2:H3)-1)
```

Comment: If it is really a Table, just used the structured referencing. The ranges will adjust automatically.

Comment: Wow, that was so easy. Thank you. I just didn't know what to google! I'll post a formal answer below

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX/MATCH to return a dynamic cell reference:

```
 =$H$2-(($H$2)/ROWS($H$2:INDEX($H:$H,MATCH(1E+99,$H:$H))))*(ROWS($H$2:H3)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply replaced `$H$2:$H$56` with the name of my table. In this case, it's name is `Table1`

```
=$H$2-(($H$2)/ROWS(Table1))*(ROWS($H$2:H3)-1)
```

Thanks Ron Rosenfeld